# Whats is the difference between join query within loop and join query using IN clause it.?

Tags: sql, database, inner-join

[image]

This is my database tables representation.

I am doing inner join to get the data from these tables 
the query is as follows.

**Query-1**

```
 select * from Trips
        Inner join TripPoints
               On Trips.tripkey=Trippoints.tripkey 
        inner join Cars
               On Trips.carid=Cars.cid 
                and Cars.cid IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
                where (lat>='4.0' and lat<='5.0')
                  and 
                (long>='52' and long <='54')
```

**Query-2**

```
    for(int carId=1;carId<=6;carId++)
        {
        select * from Trips
        Inner join TripPoints
           On         
          Trips.tripkey=TripPoints.tripkey 
          inner join Cars
          on 
          Trips.carid=Cars.cid and CARS.cid = carId
        where 
         (lat>='4.0' and lat<='5.0') 
           and 
         (long>='52' and long <='54')
        }
```

Both queries executes successfully.

But **Query-1** gives lesser records than that of **Query-2** ?

What difference in the query makes result difference?

Comment: What database are you using that has `for` loop structures?

Comment: I am using C# to build sql query and Database is mySQL 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

In the second query, this:

```
Trips.carid=Cars.cid and CARS.cid = carId
```

...will be treated as this:

```
Trips.carid = Cars.cid AND Cars.cid = Trips.carid
```

...which of course is the same as this:

```
Trips.carid = Cars.cid
```

In other words, the appearance of `carId` in the SQL is being treated as the column `carid` in table `Trips` and not your C# variable `carId` as you may be expecting. Therefore, the only semantic difference between the two queries is that the first has this:

```
and Cars.cid IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
```

...which the second does not, hence the first query returns fewer rows because there must exist `Cars.cid` values other than the values '1' to '6' inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns only one result with the info that you need (6 rows).

The second query returns 6 results because you make 6 different selects (1 row per each).

---

Each select gives a result!